# which PPA has the most current version of git for 12.04? ppa:git-core/ppa is outdated

Tags: 12.04, ppa, git

Just installed git via `ppa:git-core/ppa` and got `1.7.9.5` when the current version is `1.9.2`.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 The most current stable version of Git for Ubuntu.

For release candidates, go to https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/candidate .
...

$ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
...

$ git --version
git version 1.7.9.5
...
```

As a bonus question, why aren't there more deb packages for widely used apps like git? I know `apt-get` works fine but I find the PPA system to be kinda haphazard. I don't know if debs would be any better; just wish something better existed.

There's no tarball at http://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/list for `1.9.2`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should update your package list as version 1.9.2 is well [available](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/4076568/+listing-archive-extra) from the [`git-core` ppa](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa).

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git=1:1.9.2-0ppa1~precise1
```

Comment: damn, I forgot the update. Is there a command to add and update in one? it seems like adding a PPA and not updating is kinda pointless

Comment: I don't think so, did it solve your problem? Please accept my answer in that case. Thanks

Comment: if you want to add a ppa maybe using this [page](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa) is a bit more simple to use than the one suggested above.

Comment: added the PPA on that page and i get error: E: Version '1:1.9.2-0ppa1~precise1' for 'git' was not found -- not sure what happen. i did a update too. see: http://prntscr.com/5q6her

Comment: @duckx the ppa version has been updated I think to include a CVE fix, please try with `1:2.2.1-0ppa5~ubuntu12.04.1`

Comment: To add the git-core ppa run `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:git-core/ppa`

Comment: @Jake The command was part of the question, that's why I didn't duplicate it. But it makes sense if you're looking just at the answer, thanks.

Comment: @SylvainPineau Ah, completely missed that. I guess I'm the intended audience ;)

Answer (score 1):

Peter van der Does's PPA contains 1.9.2 for Saucy.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pdoes/ppa
```

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: My apologies. Misread the question. For some reason, my brain converted 12.04 into Saucy. :(

Comment: Sometimes pdoes's ppa is more up to date than git-core, sometimes vice versa.  The git-core ppa had git 2.3.6 packages a few days before pdoes, including for 15.04 before vivid's release date.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the bleeding edge version of `git`, then you can consider installing from the [Git release candidates PPA](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/candidate). This PPA offers installation candidates for Ubuntu from 12.04 up to 16.10, so all bases are covered. You can install from this PPA by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/candidate
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git
```